# replace median for category separated by groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

In my dataset

```
 mydat=structure(list(code = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("25480МСК", "25481МСК"), class = "factor"), 
    item = c(13163L, 13163L, 13163L, 13163L, 13163L, 13163L, 
    13164L, 13164L, 13164L, 13164L, 13164L, 13164L), sales = c(1L, 
    2L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 4L), action = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("code", 
"item", "sales", "action"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I have 2 group vars code+item. Here two groups:

```
25481МСК    13163
25480МСК    13164
```

Also i have action column. It can have only two values zero(0) or one(1).
I need calculate the median for sales by action=0 and then replace all ones(1) by action by this median.
It must be done  for each group separately.

I.E. Desired output

```
code    item    sales   action  output
25481МСК    13163   1   0        1
25481МСК    13163   2   0        2
25481МСК    13163   15  1        2
25481МСК    13163   1   0        1
25481МСК    13163   4   0        4
25481МСК    13163   3   0        3
25480МСК    13164   3   0        3
25480МСК    13164   3   0        3
25480МСК    13164   15  1        4
25480МСК    13164   4   0        4
25480МСК    13164   4   0        4
25480МСК    13164   4   0        4
```

The median by zero of action  for sales in `25481МСК    13163` group = 2, and action 1=15, so we replace action 1=15 on 2.

Note that value of sales column for action=0 also should be in  the output column.
How  perform it?

Comment: can you be more clear regarding the question. Not able to understand your output

Comment: for group 2 median is 4.

Comment: @Hunaidkhan, i  provided wrong desired output. please check edit

Comment: in output we left all value for sales by action =0 m but action=1 for sales must be replaced by median.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
librar(dplyr)
mydat %>% group_by(code,item) %>% 
          mutate(output=ifelse(action==0,sales,median(sales[action==0],na.rm = TRUE))) 


# A tibble: 12 x 5
  # Groups:   code, item [2]
  code      item sales action output
  <fct>    <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
  1 25481МСК 13163     1      0      1
  2 25481МСК 13163     2      0      2
  3 25481МСК 13163    15      1      2
  4 25481МСК 13163     1      0      1
  5 25481МСК 13163     4      0      4
  6 25481МСК 13163     3      0      3
  7 25480МСК 13164     3      0      3
  8 25480МСК 13164     3      0      3
  9 25480МСК 13164    15      1      4
  10 25480МСК 13164     4      0      4
  11 25480МСК 13164     4      0      4
  12 25480МСК 13164     4      0      4
```

Comment: Yes, it gets the desired output

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydat)
mydat[, 
      output := ifelse(action, median(sales[!action]), sales), 
      by = .(code, item)]

        code  item sales action output
 1: 25481MCK 13163     1      0      1
 2: 25481MCK 13163     2      0      2
 3: 25481MCK 13163    15      1      2
 4: 25481MCK 13163     1      0      1
 5: 25481MCK 13163     4      0      4
 6: 25481MCK 13163     3      0      3
 7: 25480MCK 13164     3      0      3
 8: 25480MCK 13164     3      0      3
 9: 25480MCK 13164    15      1      4
10: 25480MCK 13164     4      0      4
11: 25480MCK 13164     4      0      4
12: 25480MCK 13164     4      0      4
```

Comment: `replace` is another option: `mydat[, v := replace(sales, action == 1, median(sales[action == 0])), by=.(code, item)]`

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I'm not familiar with `replace` but sounds more efficient for this case.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is another approach which uses an *update join*:

```
library(data.table)
# compute medians for each group
med <- setDT(mydat)[action == 0L, median(sales), by = .(code, item)][
  # append column to pick only rows with action == 1L in join
  , action := 1L]
mydat[
  # copy sales to output column, thereby coercing to double to match value of median()
  , output := as.numeric(sales)][
    # join and update selectively
    med, on = .(code, item, action), output := V1]
mydat[]
```

> ```
>         code  item sales action output
>  1: 25481MCK 13163     1      0      1
>  2: 25481MCK 13163     2      0      2
>  3: 25481MCK 13163    15      1      2
>  4: 25481MCK 13163     1      0      1
>  5: 25481MCK 13163     4      0      4
>  6: 25481MCK 13163     3      0      3
>  7: 25480MCK 13164     3      0      3
>  8: 25480MCK 13164     3      0      3
>  9: 25480MCK 13164    15      1      4
> 10: 25480MCK 13164     4      0      4
> 11: 25480MCK 13164     4      0      4
> 12: 25480MCK 13164     4      0      4
> ```